# How to draw a image transparent in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, icon, gradient, transparency

[image]
This arrow is transparent image. 
I want to draw an icon like this image (transparent) in Photoshop.

The idea behind this is I want to colour the icon by using gradient tool in my app.

It would help me if you could suggest the steps you want us to take?

Comment: The question is how do you adjust image Opacity in Photoshop?

Comment: I'm gonna give you the benefit of the doubt and delete my messages comments, since they may very well be just me showing how close minded I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a new document the size you want.

Choose Transparent for the background....

[image]

Draw your icon.

File > Save for Web....

Choose PNG or GIF for a transparent image on the web.

Comment: The question is how do you adjust image Opacity in Photoshop?

Comment: @NerujaJoseph Ok.. I'm very confused. If you draw arrow with 100% opacity into a document that has transparent background, you would get exactly what your example image shows and that is what your question is about. Now you are asking: How to adjust the opacity of image..? Every color filling tool in photoshop has "opacity" box that you can use to fill with specific opacity _or_ if you make the new object into a new layer, you can adjust layer opacity ( or fill ) from the layers panel (`F7`).

Comment: If my answer does not actually answer your question, then you need to be **much more clear** in your question. This answer is 100% correct based upon the question.